# Unable to create or change a table without a primary key - Laravel DigitalOcean Managed Database

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration, digital-ocean

I've just deployed my app to DigitalOcean using (Managed Database) and I'm getting the following error when calling `php artisan migrate`

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3750 Unable to create or change a 
table without a primary key, when the system variable 'sql_require_primary_key'
is set. Add a primary key to the table or unset this variable to avoid
this message. Note that tables without a primary key can cause performance
problems in row-based replication, so please consult your DBA before changing
this setting. (SQL: create table `sessions` (`id` varchar(255) not null,
`user_id` bigint unsigned null, `ip_address` varchar(45) null,
`user_agent` text null, `payload` text not null, `last_activity` int not null)
default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')
```

It appears that Laravel Migrations doesn't work when mysql var `sql_require_primary_key` is set to `true`.

Do you have any solutions for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the MySQL documentation purpose of this system variable is

> to avoid replication performance issues: "Enabling this variable helps avoid performance problems in row-based replication that can occur when tables have no primary key."

IMHO, there are two possible options to consider for your problem;

- Add primary key to this and every table in your migration, including temporary tables. This one is better and i think more convenient way to do it since there is no drawback to have primary key for each table.

> Whether statements that create new tables or alter the structure of existing tables enforce the requirement that tables have a [primary key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html).

- Change your provider because according to [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/databases/mysql/) "We support only MySQL v8."

Also here is the [bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=96690)

Answer (score 85):

From March 2022, you can now configure your MYSQL and other database by making a request to digital ocean APIs.
Here's the reference: https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/databases/mysql/#4-march-2022

**STEPS TO FIX THE ISSUE:**

**Step - 1**: Create AUTH token to access digital ocean APIs. https://cloud.digitalocean.com/account/api/tokens

**STEP - 2**: Get the database cluster id by hitting the GET request to the below URL with bearer token that you have just generated above.

URL: https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/databases

**Step - 3**: Hit the below URL with PATCH request along with the bearer token and payload.

URL: [https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/databases/{YOUR_DATABASE_CLUSER_ID}/config](https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/databases/%7BYOUR_DATABASE_CLUSER_ID%7D/config)

payload: `{"config": { "sql_require_primary_key": false }}`

### That's all. It worked flawlessly.

For more information, please refer to API DOCS:
https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/databases/mysql/#latest-updates

Comment: Worked for me! Use this online post req maker  https://reqbin.com/ if you dont have postman installed

Comment: I aways get: Method not allowed

Comment: Which tool are you using to send the request to the API? Which request method are you using? @ofumbi

Comment: It needs PATCH method not PUT, maybe they changed it

Comment: @hamza ajaz personally am using my terminal and sending the requests as curl but I believe you can use tools like postman or insomnia to send those request easily

Comment: You're a life savior, I've been struggling with this since this morning. Done it with thunderclient extension in Visual Studio Code and worked flawlessly

Comment: when sending the patch request via postman, it's easiest if you send in the body/payload via "raw" option. 

thks @hamzaajaz, saved hours ;) !

Comment: Was trying to run the migrations to setup Pterodactyl and was running into this exact issue. Your solution still works in 2023!

Comment: This is amazing!!! Worked for me as well!!!! Thank you!!!

Comment: In my opinion this is a work-around, not a fix. The `sql_require_primary_key` config is used by DO for a (performance) reason, so if possible somehow I think it's better to work with it instead of against it.

Comment: `doctl databases config update <db-id> -e mysql --config-json '{ "sql_require_primary_key": false }'` worked for me

Answer (score 40):

I was trying to fix this problem with an import to DO Managed MySQL using a mysqldump file from a WordPress installation. I found adding this to the top of the file did work for my import.

```
SET @ORIG_SQL_REQUIRE_PRIMARY_KEY = @@SQL_REQUIRE_PRIMARY_KEY;
SET SQL_REQUIRE_PRIMARY_KEY = 0;
```

I then imported using JetBrains DataGrip and it worked without error.

Comment: Why not just add a primary key to the tables that were missing them before importing them?

Comment: Note that according to DigitalOcean "MySQL databases containing tables without a primary key and which contain more than 5000 rows may experience replication issues."

Comment: If you're seeing this in 2022 or later, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72438019/7437737) is what you're looking for as it doesn't require a manipulation of your mysqldump file.

Comment: I would still prefer this solution over selected answer. @darryn.ten sometimes, it may not be required. Some men just want to watch the world burn.

Answer (score 21):

Add in your first migration:

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::statement('SET SESSION sql_require_primary_key=0');
```

Inside: `Schema::create()` function.

Comment: This solves the issue for session specific cases.

Comment: You mentioned inside `Schema::create()`, however that function requires two arguments. I think you meant to put this line before `Schema::Create()` yeah?

Comment: Yes lsimonetti you're right.

Answer (score 17):

Just add `set sql_require_primary_key = off`
Like this

[image: Click to view image]

to your SQL file.

Comment: set sql_require_primary_key =off;

Comment: This sis not allowed in DigitalOcean ManagedDatabases.

Comment: Just FYI, you can set `sql_require_primary_key` off (set it to 0) on Digital Ocean managed databases. The default will always be on, but you can reset it for any session. Including a primary key on your table will always be easiest, otherwise the raw SQL to set this variable can be added to your laravel migration scripts for the tables that need it.

Answer (score 12):

One neat solution is defined [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/33238). The solution is to add listeners to migrate scripts and turn `sql_require_primary_key` on and off before and after executing a migration. This solution solve the problem where one is unable modify migrations script such as when they are from a library or a framework like Voyager.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

    use Illuminate\Database\Events\MigrationsStarted;
    use Illuminate\Database\Events\MigrationsEnded;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
    use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
    
    class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
        /**
         * Register any application services.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function register() {
    
            // check this one here https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/33238#issuecomment-897063577
            Event::listen(MigrationsStarted::class, function (){
                if (config('databases.allow_disabled_pk')) {
                    DB::statement('SET SESSION sql_require_primary_key=0');
                }
            });
    
            Event::listen(MigrationsEnded::class, function (){
                if (config('databases.allow_disabled_pk')) {
                    DB::statement('SET SESSION sql_require_primary_key=1');
                }
            });
        } 
// rest of the class 

}
```

Comment: worked like magic for me

Comment: This works on Laravel 10 and DigitalOcean

Answer (score 7):

For bigger sql file, can with this command (nano editor can open in 1 week if your file size is <8GB, lol):

First :

```
sed  -i '1i SET SQL_REQUIRE_PRIMARY_KEY = 0;' db.sql
```

Second :

```
sed  -i '1i SET @ORIG_SQL_REQUIRE_PRIMARY_KEY = @@SQL_REQUIRE_PRIMARY_KEY;' db.sql
```

Answer (score 5):

I contacted DigitalOcean via a ticket to ask if they want to disable the requirement and they did the next day :)

So you can just ask them

> Thanks for getting in touch with us!
> I understand you will like to disable the primary requirement on your managed database. The primary requirement for your managed database ****** has been disabled

Comment: Yes but note that "MySQL databases containing tables without a primary key and which contain more than 5000 rows may experience replication issues."

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, we can't change the sql_require_primary_key value in the digital ocean MySQL database. instead, you can set the id to the primary key just by adding primary()

Comment: i added it to the sql file on digitalocean and it worked

Answer (score 2):

When enabled, `sql_require_primary_key` has these effects:

1. Attempts to create a new table with no primary key fail with an error. This includes CREATE TABLE ... LIKE. It also includes CREATE TABLE ... SELECT, unless the CREATE TABLE part includes a primary key definition.
2. Attempts to drop the primary key from an existing table fail with an error, with the exception that dropping the primary key and adding a primary key in the same ALTER TABLE statement is permitted.

Dropping the primary key fails even if the table also contains a UNIQUE NOT NULL index.

3. Attempts to import a table with no primary key fail with an error.

Default value is `OFF` , but in your case you need to set `OFF` from `ON`

[IMPORTANT LINK](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_require_primary_key)

[HOW TO SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimizer-hints.html#optimizer-hints-set-var)

Comment: @Michal did you find this answer helpful,then please mark as answer or give a upvote

Answer (score 2):

If you're importing in some SQL client, just run this query on that particular database before importing.

`set sql_require_primary_key = off`

Works all good for DO managed Mysql Database. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/mysql-managed-database-can-t-modify-database-without-setting-primary-key-but-i-can-t-set-primary-key-without-modifying-the-database. I added `SET SESSION sql_require_primary_key = 0;` to the beginning of my `.sql` file that I used to import the database, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you see this error while using laravel, it's most likely from the `password_resets_table`

Update the `up()` method in your migration to below:

```
  public function up()
  {
    DB::statement('SET SESSION sql_require_primary_key=0');
    Schema::create('password_resets', function (Blueprint $table) {
      ....
    });
    DB::statement('SET SESSION sql_require_primary_key=1');
  }
```

Note: Remember to import DB

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;`

Answer (score -3):

add this line to your migration file.
$table->increments('aid');