# How to change sql_require_primary_key value permanently in MySQL 8 for Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, primary-key, digital-ocean, mysql-8.0

I recently created a database server in Digital Ocean, and it only supports MySQL 8. When I try to import a database of my Laravel project it reports this error:

> Unable to create or change a table without a primary key, when the system variable 'sql_require_primary_key' is set.

So I tried to change the sql_require_primary_key to OFF in mySQL server by running the command,

set sql_require_primary_key = off;

And it changed successfully, but after that it automatically returned to the previous setting.

In Laravel, some primary keys are set after creating the table, so it showing error while migrating. It's my live project so that I can not modify the migrations I already created.

Anyone knows how to change the sql_require_primary_key permanently on MySQL 8?

Comment: Are you using a DigitalOcean managed database?

Comment: @AlbinoDrought yes.

Comment: primary keys are really recommended. Are you sure your tables don't have a logical primary key? They have implication for shared databases which is why DO have probably set this. [invisible columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/invisible-columns.html) of a primary key might be a easy way to add one.

Comment: @danblack As I mentioned in I'm using laravel project and by default it sets the primary keys after creating the table.

Comment: There's a big discussion [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/33238) with a few work arounds.

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/266284)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to create or change a table without a primary key - Laravel DigitalOcean Managed Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62418099/unable-to-create-or-change-a-table-without-a-primary-key-laravel-digitalocean)

Comment: @philipxy I think I've clearly stated the problem here, can you please tell me if there's any confusions in my question !

Comment: The link I gave seems to ask the same question as you & the answer is you can't. If you think the answer doesn't apply then say why, including explaining your system architecture & problem in detail. I gave a link to the notion of XY problem because it seems likely that you actually have some more relevant unaddressed goal that you are trying to achieve by (possibly wrongly or needlessly) setting this mode. If possible give a [mre].

Comment: @philipxy As I mentioned my product is live, so I can't modify the migrations that I created at the beginning. The issue can be recreated by the following method. (hope you're familiar with laravel). Start new laravel project and create migration, don't mention the primary key, then create another migration to alter the table to make primary key for the table column. Then create DO database and add configuration to the laravel project, then migrate the DB, you'll get the error. Hope it helps.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS Please act on my last comment.

Answer (score 6):

A temporary workaround is to add turn `sql_require_primary_key` off for a Laravel project, you may add a statement for each database connection.

Inside `Illuminate/Session/Console/stubs/database.stub`, add this above `Schema::create()`:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
DB::statement('SET SESSION sql_require_primary_key=0');
Schema::create('sessions' ...
```

Once you have done the migration and restore, you can remove this change.

If you use Digital Ocean's API, there [documentation on the API here](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/databases/mysql/#4-march-2022). Alternatively, you may contact their support to turn that requirement off for your server.